# Pre-rendering react-snap not working; easy way to migrate cra to nextjs

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, prerender, next.js13, react-snap

I have build a react application in which there are multiple API calls integration to fetch the data as well. In order to improve performance, seo score and Google adsense integration I need to make sure crawlers are able to crawl my website. I found pre-rendering or SSR is a good option for that. I know it is achievable via nextjs but before moving there i want to explore more options for which I will have to least code changes.

In terms of pre-rendering i have tried react-snap but it is not working with react-18.

I know we have prerender.io as well for pre-rendering and SSR using nodejs. I want guidance from my community, based on their experience which will work pre-render.io or nodejs for website with rest API calls.

Also suggest if nextjs is best and only option, if yes what is the quick way to convert code. I have integration with mui, stripe, azure b2c and redux.